# Pointer arithmetic with std::vector

Tags: c++

Previously, I was working with some code in a library that had the interface

```
void f( T* x );
void g( T* x );
```

where

- `f` would fill the first `m` entries of `x` with some values (overwriting whatever is in `x`)
- `g` would fill the first `n` entries of `x` with some values (overwriting whatever is in `x`)

I wanted to concatenate these two values, so I did this

```
void concat( T* x ){
    f(x);
    x += m; 
    g(x);
    x += n; 
    ...
}
```

Actually, there were about 10 such functions that I concatenated using pointer arithmetic like this.

Now we are trying to use a different library for the same purpose. However, the new library has the interface

```
void f_new( std::vector<T> & x );
void g_new( std::vector<T> & x );
```

where again, these functions fill the first `m` and `n` elements of `x`, respectively, (overwriting whatever is currently in `x`). Furthermore, I must create a new `concat` function with the signature

```
void concat_new( std::vector<T> & x  ){
    // TODO
    ...
}
```

What is the most efficient way of achieving the previous result with vectors? 
The only way I can figure out how to do this is by copying data between calls.

NOTE: I can't modify the signatures for concat_new, f_new, or g_new

Comment: They should fill the vector

Comment: Assuming that all of the space necessary has been preallocated

Comment: What do `f_new` and `g_new` do if it already contains elements?

Comment: Overwrite whatever is there

Comment: Then there's no efficient way to do this without copying everything, unless you rewrite those functions to append.

Comment: Your new library has a worse API.

Comment: I did not write it

Comment: In case you are wondering, the older version is the interface for IPOPT. The new version that we want to use is from an automatic differentiation library (CppAD)

Answer (score 2):

There is no efficient way of doing this.

A good library should use iterators. If it does not you will have to copy the elements.

However: You can optimize a bit by reserving space for the target vector if you know the final size.

```
void concat( std::vector<T>& x ){
    x.reserve(m+n+...);
    f(x);

    std::vector<T> buffer;
    buffer.reserve(std::max({n, ...}));

    g(buffer);
    x.insert(x.end(), buffer.begin(), buffer.end());

    ...
}
```

by reusing `buffer` you can at least skip the reallocations.

---

*IF* you could change the signature of f then change it to

```
void f(std::vector<T>::iterator begin, std::vector<T>::iterator end) {
  ... // (should use 'end' at least to check the target size)
}
```

You can always use a wrapper for backward compatibility:

```
void f(std::vector<T>& x)
{ 
  f(x.begin(), x.end());
}
```

Then use

```
void concat( std::vector<T>& x) {
  assert(x.size() >= m+n);
  f(x.begin(), x.begin() + m);
  g(x.begin() + m, x.begin() + m + n);
}
```

But make sure x is large enough!

Answer (score 1):

Carry on using the old `f` and `g`, they are more applicable to you than `f_new` and `g_new`.

```
void concat_new( std::vector<T> & x  )
{
    auto it = x.data();
    f(it);
    it += m; 
    g(it);
    it += n; 
    ...
}
```

Petition the author of the library to adopt [@bartop's signatures](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49873968/2610810) (as an overload, perhaps)

Answer (score -1):

I think that instead of passing whole std::vectors, the vector's iterator would be sufficient for Your task. It gives You exactly the same functionallity as the pointer and works with vector. I'd go with something like this:

```
void concat_new( std::vector<T> & x  ){
    auto it = x.begin();
    f(x);
    it += m; 
    g(x);
    it += n; 
    ...
}
```

With it, f and g would be like this:

```
void f_new( std::vector<T>::iterator x );
void g_new( std::vector<T>::iterator x );
```

The thing that is great about it - You would not need any further changes in code if You did no evil pointer sorcery in the code.

Comment: Perhaps it wasn't clear. I can't modify the signatures for `concat_new`, `f_new`, or `g_new`

Comment: Well, I lie. I Could modify the signatures, but it would be very non-portable.

Comment: @bremen_matt Why would it be so?

Comment: Suppose we want to minimize (in the mathematical sense) the sum of squares of some vector `f(x)`. Great. The original and new library are perfectly suited for that... Both libraries define `f`. Now suppose that I want to minimize the sum of squares of the augmented vector `[ f(x), g(x) ]`. I do not want to change the signature of `f` because then it would not work in both cases.

Comment: In the first case, the signature with just the vector is precisely what we want. In the second, we want the iterator.

Comment: I could overload some stuff, but that will lead to a lot of redundant code

Comment: But if there is no better way of implementing this than overloading, then I will just have to do it. I thought that perhaps the `placement new` construct may somehow be relevant to this problem

Comment: @bremen_matt "it would not work in both cases" why is that exactly?

Comment: If the cost was `f` alone, then I can just pass the vector directly. If it is the augmented form, then I need to concatenate (and then I need the other signature).

Comment: You keep adding info in comments in a haphazard and unsystematic manner. You may want to slow down, write up a different question, and ask it. In other news you almost never want a vector in a function signature, you want an iterator or a pair of iterators.